# HTML - iframe to import page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, iframe

I need to import one page to my Wordpress server. And this page is one project with chatbox.

I try use iframe tag, but it does not work, show only one white page inside `iframe` tag.

I search about that, and some knowledge said it is because I use other host to access and my server use other host.

Reference: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

In this case, if I paste my project (Is one web project) in the same server (host) Wordpress, my application will works fine with `iframe` tag?

Example, my Wordpress will have this code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://10.0.1.101:3000" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want put one chatbox inside my Wordpress site. My project have some backend and front end in nodejs, I want this project start inside my Wordpress page.

If I did something wrong please let me know. I dont find anything about that. If someone have some suggestions, I accept.

Thanks advance.

Comment: Can your "Wordpress Server" see this host: 10.0.1.101:3000? If this is your local ip address the remote server can't open it.

Comment: also there is no protocol in the url

Comment: the host is on the same network. What I can do to solved this?

Comment: 1. Try start url with http://, 2. Try open this link in your browser directly, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't src="10.0.1.101:3000" be src="http://10.0.1.101:3000" ?

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://10.0.1.101:3000" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```